# How to use a HashMap returned from a method

Tags: java, class, hashmap, return, return-value

Here I have a program which creates a HashMap within a method

```
import java.util.HashMap;


class Evan {
  public HashMap<String,Double> abilities_get() {
     HashMap<String,Double> abilities = new HashMap<String,Double>();
     abilities.put("stealth", 1.5);
     abilities.put("strength", 1.2);
     abilities.put("accuracy", 1.0);
     abilities.put("intelligence", 2.0);
     return abilities;
     
 }
 }

 public class Main {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Evan evan = new Evan();
       evan.abilities_get();
       abilities.get("stealth");
}
}
```

This program doesn't work due to the fact that in the main method "abilities" cannot be found. How can I make it so I can use my HashMap in the main function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Evan {
    public HashMap<String,Double> abilities_get() {
        HashMap<String,Double> abilities = new HashMap<String,Double>();
        abilities.put("stealth", 1.5);
        abilities.put("strength", 1.2);
        abilities.put("accuracy", 1.0);
        abilities.put("intelligence", 2.0);
        return abilities;

    }
}

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Evan evan = new Evan();
        evan.abilities_get();
        Double stealth = evan.abilities_get().get("stealth");
        System.out.println(stealth);
    }
}
```

Try it out

Comment: Thank you so much man! I was looking for this forever but it was just a quick addition apparently (I'll accept this as the answer in a couple minutes because there's a timer on how fast I can accept an answer).

Comment: It's hard at first. I advise you to view ready-made examples from github. The main thing is not to give up!
Do you need comments on the code?

Comment: I'm all good I believe I understand it, thank you though.